# Add to a list of strings checking for duplicates and appending on a number at the end

Tags: c#, string

I have a list of strings

```
var lsNameList = new List<string>();
```

that is a list of file names. 
I want to iterate over a collection of files checking the file names for matches. If there is a match then append on a number. the number will be increments in one. eg If filename is in the list then append on 1 so it will be filename1. If filename1 is in the list then change it to filename2 and so on.

```
foreach (var SourceFile in SourceFiles)
  if (lsNameList.Contains(SourceFile.Label.ToLower()))
     // Add the name to the list but with a number at the end
```

I have the iteration and filename checking done but I have a problem when the number runs into double digits

```
var sLastCharacter = SourceFile.Label[SourceFile.Label.Length - 1].ToString();
var iLast = StringToInt(sLastCharacter);
```

What if SourceFile.Label is filename10. The last digit will be 0 and we will start all over again causing a infinite loop.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: which version of .net? can you use linq?

Comment: What if file has name `42` without letters?

Comment: Can you keep track of changes you've made in file names? I think you should provide more info about your scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't check only the last character but the whole number and parse it to an `int`. But i would use a separator between the name and the number, otherwise it's a problem if the filename itself ends with a number.

You could use Linq with a custom method to increment the number and add it to the other collection:

```
IEnumerable<String> newPaths = SourceFiles
    .Select(sf => AddIncrementFileNameSuffix(sf.Label, lsNameList,"_"));
```

and here's all the "magic"

```
public static string AddIncrementFileNameSuffix(string path, IList<string> paths, string separator)
{
    string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(path);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
    string[] tokens = fileName.Split(new[] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    int num = 0;
    int.TryParse(tokens.Last(), out num);

    var dups = paths.Where(n => n.Equals(path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    while (dups.Any())
    {
        path = Path.Combine(dir, tokens.First() + separator + ++num + ext);
    }

    paths.Add(path);
    return path;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/Uj0R6m)

Answer (score 1):

Can add  a function that gets from the end the file all possible digits:

so (a *pseudocode*)

```
var resultString = string.Empty;
for(int i=SourceFile.Label.Length - 1,i>=0;i--)
{
   var ch = SourceFile.Label[i];
   if(Char.IsNumber(ch))
     resultString = new string(ch) + resultString; //ADD IN FRONT
}

var iLast = StringToInt(resultString );
```

This is in case where you can not change the file name format. But if you can, you can add just a separator before number, say "_". So when you split the name of the file by that, you will know that on the right side there are only numbers you need.

Comment: This will not work in case the filename itself has digits at its end.

Comment: @sohil: agree, for this I add a second option too. There **has to be**  some way to know. It could be some char (separator), or the notion that file name has not numbers in it, or maximum possible numbers string length, or something else...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach (var SourceFile in SourceFiles)
  if (lsNameList.Contains(SourceFile.Label.ToLower()))
  {
    int i = 1;
    while (lsNameList.Contains(SourceFile.Label.ToLower() + i.ToString()))
      i++;
    //add file with i as number
  }
```

Comment: Maybe comment as to why you're downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var SourceFile in SourceFiles)
{
    if (lsNameList.Contains(SourceFile.Label.ToLower()))
    {
        int fileNumber = 1;
        while (lsNameList.Contains((SourceFile.Label + fileNumber).ToLower()))
        {
           fileNumber++;
        }
        SourceFile.Label = SourceFile.Label + fileNumber;
    }
    lsNameList.Add(SourceFile.Label.ToLower());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ to get a list of duplicates and then append the number to the end of each, like so:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "filename", "filename", "42", "another_file", "another_file" };
foreach (var item in list.Distinct().ToArray())
{
    var duplicates = list.Where(temp => temp == item).ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < duplicates.Length; i++)
    {
        duplicates[i] = string.Concat(item, (i + 1).ToString());
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assuming that only the last character of the string will be the count, you should use all the characters (you could use Substring()), ignoring only the original filename.